# How can I keep track of the prior node in a binary search tree in-order method?

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

My question is very simple. I'm using Java to carry out a binary search tree in-order traversal(recursively), and somehow I need to compare the node value between the last one I encountered and the current one to see if the whole tree is a binary search tree or not. I used a signature like this below:

```
private void helper(List<TreeNode> list,TreeNode p,TreeNode q)
```

In this method, by `p` I mean the current node I'm dealing with, by `q` I mean the last one I dealt with. I'm having trouble writing the method. So please share your knowledge on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need the list of TreeNodes as a parameter for this helper method because when you pass in the root node it will already include all of the other TreeNodes. Here is a method that determines if the binary tree is in correct order. (Start by passing the root node into the public helper method):

```
public boolean helper(TreeNode root)
    {
        if (root.getLeftNode() == null)
        {
            if (root.getRightNode() == null)
                return true;
            else return helper(root.getRightNode(), root);
        }
        //if everything branching from leftNode is in order
        else if(helper(root.getLeftNode(), root))
        {
            if (root.getRightNode() != null)
                return helper(root.getRightNode(), root);
            else return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }

    private boolean helper(TreeNode currentNode, TreeNode previousNode)
    {
        //Test leftNode
        if (currentNode == previousNode.getLeftNode())
        {
            if (currentNode.getData() > previousNode.getData()) return false;
            else
            {
                if (currentNode.getLeftNode() == null)
                {
                    if (currentNode.getRightNode() == null)
                        return true;
                    else return helper(currentNode.getRightNode(), currentNode);
                }
                //if everything branching from leftNode is in order
                else if(helper(currentNode.getLeftNode(), currentNode))
                {
                    if (currentNode.getRightNode() != null)
                        return helper(currentNode.getRightNode(), currentNode);
                    else return true;
                }
                else return false;
            }
        }
        //Test rightNode
        else
        {
            if (currentNode.getData() < previousNode.getData()) return false;
            else
            {
                if (currentNode.getLeftNode() == null)
                {
                    if (currentNode.getRightNode() == null)
                        return true;
                    else return helper(currentNode.getRightNode(), currentNode);
                }
                //if everything branching from leftNode is in order
                else if(helper(currentNode.getLeftNode(), currentNode))
                {
                    if (currentNode.getRightNode() != null)
                        return helper(currentNode.getRightNode(), currentNode);
                    else return true;
                }
                else return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is assuming you are using a TreeNode class similar to this one:

```
public class TreeNode
{
    private TreeNode leftNode;
    private TreeNode rightNode;
    private int data;

    public TreeNode(int data, TreeNode leftNode, TreeNode rightNode)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.leftNode = leftNode;
        this.rightNode = rightNode;
    }

    public TreeNode getLeftNode()
    {
        return leftNode;
    }
    public TreeNode getRightNode()
    {
        return rightNode;
    }
    public int getData()
    {
        return data;
    }
}
```

I'm sure this could be written better and more efficiently, but I hope this gets you on the right track at least.

Comment: The data structure you assumed is basically same as I am using. You wrote a piece of rather lengthy code, and I think the logic of the method is quite complicated, but after I deducing step by step throughout  I know you are right. I sometimes feel that writing a recursive method is quite tricky, and I want some suggestion of yours,thanks.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about the length but I'm glad that it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

For checking Tree is BST or Not we can do inorder traversal.
While doing In-Order traversal, we can keep track of previously visited node. If the value of the currently visited node is less than the previous value, then tree is not BST.

```
public class IsBstTest {

private static TreeNode prevNode;  

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TreeNode root = new TreeNode(4);
    root.left = new TreeNode(2);
    root.right = new TreeNode(5);
    root.right.left = new TreeNode(6);
    root.right.right = new TreeNode(7);

    if (isBst(root))
        System.out.println("Is BST");
    else
        System.out.println("Not a BST");
}

public static Boolean isBst(TreeNode root) {
    if (root != null) {
        if (!isBst(root.left)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (prevNode != null && root.value <= prevNode.value) {
            return false;
        }
        prevNode = root;
        return isBst(root.right);
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

And TreeNode is:

```
public class TreeNode {

public int value;

public TreeNode left;

public TreeNode right;

public TreeNode(int value) {
    this.value = value;
}
}
```

Comment: Your solution is succinct and smart! It didn't occur to me to use the static variable to track down the previous node until I see your solution. Very enlightening. Thanks